`?_gl` query parameter is added to my URL links to my subdomain - how to remove it?
I'm using Wordpress and on my site I have link to my subdomain. When I click the link it adds query parameter _gl. I don't want it. I want my link to look clean.
How to turn it off?
When I click link it looks like:
https://mysubdomain.mydomain.org/?_gl=1*...*_ga*...*_ga_....*....
where ... are some random changing code.

So I figured out. _gl parameter was added because of Google Analytics 4. And in my Wordpress it was enabled by plugin Site Kit by Google.

simple solution to remove it, one can just disable whole Site Kit plugin.
DON'T FORGET TO Clear Post Cache in your Wordpress wp-admin console. Just cos I did't I spent another hour figuring why it didn't disappeared cos probably bloody CDN remembered scripts...

Anyway this means your Google Analytics will not work at all on your site. Which might not be an ideal solution.

better solution I found out I can keep Site Kit enabled and just add following Javascript code:
window.addEventListener("load", function() {     
  if (window.google_tag_data && indow.google_tag_data.gl.decorators){
    window.google_tag_data.gl.decorators = [];
  }
 });



(Again don't forget to Celar Post Cache.)
You can add javascript easily for example using plugin Simple Custom CSS and JS By SilkyPress.com.
I did set javascript to be added in <footer>.
Now what you lost by removing this _gl parameter? You lost cross-domain analytics. Meaning if one person comes from your domain to your subdomain he will be counted twice... Boo hoo. I don't care... Although I understand it's cool feature, not worthy for me to have ugly URL...

There might be even better solution to remove it in your subdomain so cross domain analysis would even work... I didn't try this solution cos I did not need it and it was more code. But here it is: Cross-Domain tracking with clean urls - by David Vallejo


Also I would be happy if someone would figure out how to turn _gl query parameter off directly in Google Analytics 4 settings (https://analytics.google.com/)...
I already tried in Admin->Data Streams->click your data stream->Configure tag settings:

Configure your domains. I removed all my domains from there or then later also tried add all of them them and nothing worked...
Show More->List unwanted referrals and I filled all my domains and subdomains and didn't help either.

And note somewhere I saw people were guiding how to remove it from reporting. That is useless for me I want to remove it from my URL link so link looks nice...

_gl is part of cross-domain tracking. Disable it and it will go away. Make sure you're disabling it for the correct measurement id. The one on the destination site

@BNazaruk Actually I originally tried to remove all domains from Configure your domains on source site (as that is site which adds the query parameter). But on you advice I tried to delete also all domains from Configure your domains on destination side. And still same result. Fucking google just adds _gl parameter anyway... Where else I can try to kill it??

well, you may be doing it from GTM if you're still using some deprecated tags from GA UA. It's actually easy to test by blocking certain scripts in devtools and finding which one is responsible that way.

@BNazaruk. Well I set up all like week ago. I install Google site kit. And basically only clicked next few times... So no possibility for anything old anywhere...
Also there is only one script added I think. It's this one: 
And it's somewhat compiled so I can not read nothing in it... Is there a way to get from google uncompiled version?

That's gtm. it doesn't append anything. But it loads gtag, which does.
